# Unsandboxing a solution gives a Web Part Error

Tags: sandbox-solution

I'm extremely new to SharePoint and most definitely not our company's SharePoint dev. They set me up with a WebPart and its project where I can write some code.

The page was working perfectly fine when in a Sandbox. I needed to unsandbox it, so I can send out emails, and only flipping the "Sandbox" bit and changing literally nothing else, following a deploy I now get a

```
Web Part Error: The request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found.
```

When reverting back to a Sandbox it starts working again. Any chance this is a simple fix ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to

- backup your solution ,
- go to project properties , set sandbox solution to false
- Apply the steps on each project in the current solution
- Save and reopen the solution again,
- build and deploy

Hope it helps !

Comment: Turned out flipping it back and forth most likely changes the WebPart's ID back and forth. It required removing the webpart and adding it again. Thanks anyway.